# Adding emmet plugin to Vim in Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, plugin-emmet-vim

I am using Vim in my windows PC . Currently I am working with a web project and I want to use Vim as code editor.

I tried to download and add the http://emmet.io/ plugin to Vim editor from [this site](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim) but couldn't get how to do it. The documentation I found is only for Linux machine. Can any body help?

Comment: Related: [Plugin for Vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, lets view the steps listed in the `README` for installing the plugin in Linux. the steps are:

1. Download the zip.
2. run `cd ~/.vim`
3. run `unzip emmet-vim.zip`

I'm assuming you know how to do the first step.

The second step requires you to **c**hange **d**irectory into the `~/.vim` folder - the folder where (also) the plugins are saved on Linux systems. This folder on windows gVim is called `vimfiles`, so just open the file explorer in the installation directory of gVim, and open the `vimfiles` folder.

The third step is extracting the contents of `emmet-vim.zip` into the folder you navigated to in the previous step. You should be able to do that quite easily in windows.

The answer is based on the following doc: [Simple steps to help you install gVim on windows 7](http://www.vim.org/ugrankar.pdf)